# Code on MDN: how does this IE specific shim for setTimer work?

Tags: javascript

On [MDN's page for setTimer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#Callback_arguments), there is a little shim / compatibility layer for setTimer that will let Internet Explorer accept additional arguments in the setTimer method that will be passed to the callback.

I pretty much understand all of the code below:

```
if (document.all && !window.setTimeout.isPolyfill) {
  var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout;
  window.setTimeout = function (
                          vCallback, 
                          nDelay /*, 
                          argumentToPass1, 
                          argumentToPass2, etc. */
                          ) {
    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
      vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
    } : vCallback, nDelay);
  };
  window.setTimeout.isPolyfill = true;
}
```

Except for one line:

```
var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

It references `arguments`, but I cannot see that name being referenced anywhere before this line. It is not on the [Reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) list either, so it does not seem to be *magic* in any way. In order for me to make any sense out of it, it must somehow refer to the arguments of the overridden setTimeout function, and then use `slice()` to get every argument after the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `arguments` holds all the arguments that were passed to a function including those, that were not named in the function declaration.

Remember, that assuming the following function

```
function doStuf( param1 ) { /* do something */ }
```

it is also valid to make such a call

```
doStuff( 'stuff', 'morestuff', 2, 'evenmorestuff' );
```

In that case you could reference all parameters using the `arguments` object.

---

So in your particular code, the following row

```
var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

copies all arguments passed to the shim-function, but the first two. The first two, however, were explicitly named and are referenced as such (`vCallback` and `nDelay`).

- [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Answer (score 1):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is indeed magic; it's an object very similar to an array that contains the arguments passed to the current function. This object has local scope inside all functions.

Since it is not *exactly* an array, the pattern `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` is commonly used to extract a number of (or all) the argument values into a real array. In this specific case, `aArgs` ends up being an array that contains all arguments passed to the `setTimeout` replacement apart from the first two.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments` *is* magic - it's the arguments that were passed to a function, in array form.

See [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) on MDN: *"An Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function [...] available within all functions"*

Comment: OK, so it is not a reserved word per se, as you probably can overwrite it by specifying another var arguments = {}. But in that case there should be another list on MDN, being a superset of reserved words, specifying all these magic words as well :)

Comment: @oligofren: You're right, and a cursory search didn't find it.  If you find such a thing, please post a link here!